# Shortcode wordpress php

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

How do i add a shortcode around this code:

```
    <a rel="nofollow" href="<?php the_field('download_link',$taxonomy . '_' . $term_id); ?>"target="_blank">DOWNLOAD LINK 1</a>
```

I have already tried the code below. It doesn't actually activate the short code.

```
    [sociallocker]
    <a rel="nofollow" href="<?php the_field('download_link',$taxonomy . '_' . $term_id); ?>"target="_blank">DOWNLOAD LINK 1</a>
     [/sociallocker]
```

Comment: so show how you added the sociallocker shortcode to WP. you acn't just throw some random text inside `[]` and expect WP to know what to do... it has to be registered with `add_shortcode()`

Comment: FYI: At least for Facebook, that plugin (assuming this is what you are talking about, https://wordpress.org/plugins/social-locker/) clearly violates their Platform Policy – Like Gating is not allowed by Facebook any more, and neither is rewarding users for liking/posting/sharing in any other way.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API), you can find a lots of examples how you can implement this. Here is a possible solution:

```
function download_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return '<a rel="nofollow" href="' .  the_field('download_link',$atts['taxonomy'] . '_' . $atts['term_id']); . '" target="_blank">DOWNLOAD LINK 1</a>';
}
add_shortcode( 'download', 'download_shortcode' );
```

> When used like this:

```
[download taxonomy=text1 term_id=text2]
```

> The output would be:

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="/*The response from the function*/" target="_blank">DOWNLOAD LINK 1</a>
```

---

So, this function *download_shortcode()* should be in your theme's functions.php file, or in a separate plugin. The only problem here is that you can't pass php code there (inside, as content or as parameters), so you have to choose, add parameters to the shortcode (the taxonomy/term fields), or insert content between opening and closing [download][/download] shortcodes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're trying to accomplish. Is this code in a template where you want to use the shortcode? If so, you need to use the `do_shortcode` function, like so:

```
echo do_shortcode('[sociallocker]<a rel="nofollow" href="' . the_field('download_link',$taxonomy . '_' . $term_id) . '" target="_blank">DOWNLOAD LINK 1</a>[/sociallocker]');
```